# JSON variables in List

Tags: apex, rest-api, json

I am getting the following JSON from api and trying to add some of the variables in the list of "filings" to a custom object.

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "success": true,
  "message": "string",
  "errors": [
    {
      "subCode": "string",
      "message": "string"
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "configuredWorkflow": [
      {
        "name": "string",
        "requiresCommentToTransition": true,
        "rank": 0
      }
    ],
    "filings": [
      {
        "referenceId": "string",
        "title": "string",
        "reportId": "string",
        "workflowStep": "string",
        "comments": "string",
        "accountId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "accountName": "string",
        "companyId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "companyName": "string",
        "countryCode": "string",
        "dueDate": "2020-05-28T08:00:38Z",
        "filingArtifact": "string",
        "filingArtifactName": "string"
      }
    ],
    "count": 0
  }
}
```

I have used http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ to create following class:

```
public class JSON2Apex {

    public class Errors {
        public String subCode;
        public String message;
    }

    public Integer status;
    public Boolean success;
    public String message;
    public List<Errors> errors;
    public Data data;

    public class Data {
        public List<ConfiguredWorkflow> configuredWorkflow;
        public List<Filings> filings;
        public Integer count;
    }

    public class ConfiguredWorkflow {
        public String name;
        public Boolean requiresCommentToTransition;
        public Integer rank;
    }

    public class Filings {
        public String referenceId;
        public String title;
        public String reportId;
        public String workflowStep;
        public String comments;
        public String accountId;
        public String accountName;
        public String companyId;
        public String companyName;
        public String countryCode;
        public String dueDate;
        public String filingArtifact;
        public String filingArtifactName;
    }


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

I then pass json to the class and get the list of filings. I want to to loop through and then refer to variables from the Fileing class but cant.

```
   JSON2Apex class1 = JSON2Apex.parse(workflowResponse);
       list<object> filingslist  = class1.data.filings;
       for(Object eachfiling : filingslist){               

        }
```

How do I get at the different variables in "eachfiling" . what else do I need to do to ?

Comment: Why are you typing `filingsList` as a `List<Object>`? I'd imagine that your problems will disappear if you used the appropriate type (`List<JSON2Apex.Filings>`). As usual, if you're getting an error, you should include the full text of the error, verbatim. You should also use the appropriate type for your loop variable.

Comment: why not use `Json.deserialize` instead of `JSON2Apex.parse`?

Answer (score 0):

This solves your problem:

```
JSON2Apex class1 = JSON2Apex.parse(wf);
list<JSON2Apex.Filings> filingslist  = class1.data.filings;

 for(JSON2Apex.Filings m : filingslist){    
      system.debug(m.accountId);
      system.debug(m.companyName);
 }
 }
```